# CSS text sliding animation failed to work

Tags: html, css, animation

> The intros is a div which has some `<h1>` and `<p>` tags inside it. I want the text to slide in from the right side but it is not working.

```
 .intros {
   color: rgb(49, 49, 49);
   font-family: Raleway;
   animation: heading;
   animation-duration: 2s;
   animation-fill-mode: forwards;
 }  

@keyframes heading {
 0% {right: -700px}
 100% {right: 51%} 
}
```

Comment: The intros is a div which has h1 and p tags inside it*

Comment: Please include your html so that we can see what you are working with and work out where the problem is. Take a look at how to create a [minimal,reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so we can see the error and are able to help you fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See changes in the source code.

```css
.intros {
  color: rgb(49, 49, 49);
  font-family: Raleway;
  animation: heading;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  position: relative; /* Added */
}

@keyframes heading {
  0% {
    right: -700px
  }
  100% {
    right: 0; /* Changed */
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="intros">
  <h1>Text</h1>
  <p>Text</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, it worked. Can you please explain what position:relative does here?

Comment: Position relative makes sure the elements obey the right position. By default, the position is static. You can find more details [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position).